# d3.js in Lightning Component - TypeError: cannot use the given object as a weak map key throws in Firefox

Tags: lightning-aura-components, d3

this error appears in Firefox (56.0) when trying to run (d3.js v4):

```
 svg = svg.call(d3.zoom().on("zoom", zoomed)).append("g"); 
or 
.call(d3.drag()...
```

in Lightning component.

error:
TypeError: cannot use the given object as a weak map key throws at https://c.cs83.visual.force.com/auraFW/javascript/adfsdfghjjJGH/aura_prod.js:749:168

I found posts about the same issue in very old versions of Firefox. 
Also it works in Chrome

Comment: Firefox 57.0 - the issue is still there

Comment: Anyone have any information on this yet?

Comment: Yes, There is an issue with locker service. If locker service is disabled then it's working with D3 V4. The issue is with locker service and firefox. @TrevorBliss  Any idea?

Comment: Is this resolved? any update. We seems to have similar issue too while using swipe.